# Catalina > Mojave on old MacBook Pro

Tags: itunes, backup, time-machine

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro updated from Mojave to Catalina. Want Mojave back principally for iTunes. Catalina was released Oct, 2019. I have TM backup from August 2019 that should have Mojave on it. I just made a new backup onto a different external drive from the one previously used for TM backups. My question: is is safe just to follow Apple instructions to do this? Just use Disk Utility to erase Mac HD and restore with the August TM backup? Thanks for help!  Ron

Comment: yah that should work. Note I say should. I've been doing support for a loooong time and nothing is guaranteed. Personally I'd make a Mojave installer on an 8GB USB thumb drive, just in case. Oh and I'd also make an image of your drive as it currently is, just in case...

Comment: Everything @SteveChambers said with the addition of copying your *data* like documents, pictures, and such to another drive - a cloud service (iCloud, OneDrive, etc.) so in the event that everything goes sideways, you still have your data.  I like to have my data in a least 3 places to be safe.